# Deserializing an array that can contain multiple types

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have some JSON that can hold an array of both arrays of maps, or just maps (I know this seems dumb). I'm having trouble identifying what the ArrayOrMap class should look like to allow deserialisation of this structure.

```
{
  "example": [
      [
        {
          "key1": "value1"
        },
        {
          "key2": "value2"
        }
      ],
      {
        "key3": "value3"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialise this using ObjectMapper, and Jackson's @JsonCreator annotations:

```
    @Getter
    static class StackOverflowExample {
        private final ArrayOrMap[] example;

        @JsonCreator
        StackOverflowExample (
                @JsonProperty("example") ArrayOrMap[] example,
        ) {
            this.example = example;
        }
    }

    @Getter
    static class ArrayOrMap {
        ???
    }

    ...
    // code that attempts to deserialise
    final StackOverflowExample result = objectMapper.readValue(
            data,
            StackOverflowExample.class
    );
```

I'm trying to deserialise the JSON into an array of objects, each of which can be either an array of maps, or just a map, but I don't know what the class for ArrayOrMap should look like. It seems like object deserialisation always requires a key of some kind, but here I'm just deserialising an array of objects, so I don't have a key to look at.

I'm aware that the structure of this JSON is pretty poor to begin with, but changing it now would take significant effort.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Writing the low level parsing using the https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api streaming api is probably your only chance to deserialize the `example` key.  Or revisit just how "significant" the change to a better structure is?